# Strange reputation accounting on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

I just got two upvotes from this Stack Overflow question:

*[How to override master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42812863/how-to-override-master/42812907#42812907)*

I'm seeing really bizarre behavior right now. On the Stack Overflow question page above, my rep level has increased by 20 points. But my achievements do not reflect this at all:

[image]

Similarly, the Meta site shows my total reputation also not reflecting these 20 points:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: It's just caching.  These things don't all update in real time.

Comment: @Servy If you have duplicate link, show it and I'll kill this question.  In 3 years I have never seen this behavior before.

Comment: Yeah, can reproduce. I have a vote from 6 minutes ago on Meta that doesn't show up there and I only know about because the post gave me a bronze badge because of the vote. Seems new events aren't making it into the dialog right now.

Comment: Looks like the caching between meta and main is in sync.  When I look at your meta profile I see 87,686 REPUTATION.  Do you see that now?

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it has been in sync for the last 5 minutes or so, but not at the time I posted.  I hope this doesn't end up being one of those Superman II things where someone is stealing 10 points from every SO user in an effort to surpass Jon Skeet.

Comment: @NathanOliver The bug seems strictly confined to the achievements dialog. The events *do* show up in the reputation history, and reputation is being added correctly.

Comment: @animuson I figured.  I just know that meta rep can lag behind main rep So i wanted to make sure that was the case here since the OP said it had the wrong value on meta.

Comment: I noticed this on the app last night, but it seemed fine on the site at the time. App showed no rep but loading in browser did

Comment: Update: I just got marked right on a question, and the achievements _partially_ corrected themselves.  At first, the question I cited above only showed 10 points, when in fact the page itself showed 20.  However, about 20-30 seconds later, I got credited with +10, and after that everything appeared synched up again.  Probably a caching issue.

Comment: Looks like it's all normal again.

Comment: @adam Nick Craver fault?

Comment: @Braiam Nah, this time he's innocent.

Comment: I've had some really bad caching before; a week ago I got a +5 reputation bonus for an answer that included a link to Docs that I had contributed to, but the answer hadn't been edited in over a year.

Comment: @TylerH That's not caching. That's bug fixes in Docs and rep recalcs.

Answer (score 18):

The stuff in the Achievements dialog comes from a network-wide rep history table that's populated by what we affectionately refer to as "the aggregator".

A change was made to the aggregator earlier today... and then we forgot to actually, you know, build the project that runs it out to production in addition to the normal Q&A prod builds. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The build went out a few hours ago, so things should be back to normal.

Comment: manual builds!! *gasps*

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Eh? Dev-tier builds are automatic. Going automatically to production sounds like a recipe for a bad time. :)

Comment: What could *possibly* go wrong™? ;)