# Is the rep widget broken again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, achievements-dialog

I just had an answer marked correct on Stack Overflow, and my rep number in the top status bar has not updated yet, as of about 10 minutes ago.  In addition, the achievements icon does not reflect the question either.

Is something broken/being updated right now?

Comment: Can confirm.. but the rep is added if you check in the profile..

Comment: MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293094/why-does-the-reputation-dropdown-not-show-this-upvote

Comment: @Stijn This may be a dupe, insofar that it's happened before (it happened 2-3 weeks ago actually), but it's definitely _not_ normal or business as usual.

Comment: The linked question is 45 minutes old :) just confirming that it is indeed broken right now.

Comment: @suraj My profile reflects the correct answer in the "Answers" section, but the rep number is wrong.

Comment: Yes, the achievement dialog stopped updating sometime between 07:15 and 07:45 today (rough times of my last acknowledged achievement, and the first that went by without update).

Comment: seems to be broken still

Comment: They made some substantial UI/server changes during the refactor of the top status bar.  Since then, these quirks have been intermittently happening.  Also, the experience with the full site on Android mobile has been a bit off since then.

Comment: Update: Because this question got 12 upvotes, I earned a Nice Answer badge and I _was_ notified of this.  Still no points though.

Comment: ^^--- Then there's something really messed up ; ).

Comment: We are aware of things being broken - the process that syncs reputation (and other things) across the network is backed up. We are working on fixing it.

Comment: Update 8pm Singapore time: I received 10 points in my inbox, but my other missing rep still isn't there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yea, me too, I received @ approx 8:20pm (also Singapore time).

Comment: Wheee, some data managed to get through. Not complete yet, but the pipe opened for a brief moment. :-)

Comment: I just received notification for all the missing reputation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You don't receive reputation for meta posts. Your meta reputation should be kept in sync with your main Stack Overflow profile's reputation.

Comment: ...phew.... this is some pretty intense stuff for some more imaginary internet points for an 90k+ rep user...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: It is possible to care about improving a system without selfishly depending on the improvements.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition don't misinterpret me, I am fully aware that something needs fixing, it's the particular tone I am commenting about. Maybe I am misunderstanding that. Also, this has been asked a few weeks ago, on mso, trying to find the question.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: I perceive no "tone".

Comment: @Oded is the suggested edits limits included in "(and other things)"?

Comment: @Braiam - no. That's not something that is cross-network.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: this issue was new today.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, right, it just *looked* [the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345461). the achievement popup not showing reputation changes does seem to be much alike.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: right, but as you can see that that issue was marked as completed. Today the same subsystem got stuck somewhere, but the root cause may well be different.

Comment: @Oded  I just ran into this or something related to it, [right now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293094/why-does-the-reputation-dropdown-not-show-this-upvote#comment952521_293094), if you care. A rep change on MSE, approximately 10 minutes ago, not shown in dropdown.

Comment: @Jas - yes, likely related.

Comment: Yes it's seriously broken. From today afternoon, am observing this behavior. even now also can see it's happening. Am getting upvotes and my total reputation score reflecting it but the "Recent Achievements" is not tracking it. Looks like a bug

Comment: @Oded Now I've been getting repeat notifications (rep change indicator on top bar) for the same events (including the previously missing one) for about 30 minutes or so.

Comment: @JasonC - yes, things are still not fully resolved. Our best people are on it.

Comment: Is this related to the 500 error trying to view my own rep page?

Comment: @Machavity Shouldn't be. Please post at new bug report if you're still getting an error.

Comment: @Oded, any update on this. Is this not resolved yet? Cause I still see it present. yesterday night I got 3 upvotes (30 points) which I see still missing from "Recent Achievement" section

Comment: @Rahul - It should be mostly resolved. I believe there was some bad data that had to be removed from a queue, which may be what is causing what you are seeing.

Comment: See the official answer from Oded on MSE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293175/245360).

Comment: @Oded Will the achievements re-sync to match what happened or not?  My achievements window is missing 49 rep worth of activities still from yesterday.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I don't believe it will.

Comment: @Oded OK.  Just wanted to know.  Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the [status-completed] tell enough, and must this question really be closed? Closing this question will rob the developent team from posting an answer stating that the bug is fixed.

Comment: @Oded This might be happening again.

Comment: @NathanOliver - what makes you say that?

Comment: @Oded I have an upvote and accept on an answer that never showed as a notification: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Wd8.png

Comment: @Oded plus, my meta.SE [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295003/280934)'s upvotes are nowhere to be seen. (Which is more recent than Nathan's answer)

Comment: I'll take a look - I know there were some changes there recently.